# Help to review my game

Tags: discussion

I currently play at chess.com (free account) and I review some games after that I played but I don't know whether my thoughts are good about some decision. Would be here the right place to post some game to review it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, such questions are certainly welcome at the main site.

Comment: Thanks ETD. I'll do.